# Cypress conditional statement not working as expected

Tags: html, automated-tests, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Code:

```
<ul> <li> <h1>source</h1> <label>completed</label> </li> <li> <h1>source</h1> <label>Failed</label> </li> <li> <h1>new test</h1> <label>completed</label> </li> </ul>
```

Context: I have code like this inside ul I have several li elements. I need to write a if else statement using Cypress. If li element has text source in h1 and label has text `Completed` I need to click on that element else skip.

Comment: Please post the code snippet you tried along with the error that you are getting.

Comment: <ul>
<li>
<h1>source</h1>
<label>completed</label>
</li>
<li>
<h1>source</h1>
<label>Failed</label>
</li>
<li>
<h1>new test</h1>
<label>completed</label>
</li>
</ul>

Answer (score 0):

I would try to convert the content of the li element to string, and do conditional statement according to that:

```
cy.get('li')
    .each($element => {
        if($element.innerHtml().includes("source") && $element.innerHtml().includes("completed")) {
            $element.click()
        }
    })
```

Edit 2: If there are multiple elements that can be valid and you are stuck in a loop - recursion is better

```
cy.get('li')
.then(elements => {
        let i = 0

        function checkElementsAdnClick(arrayOfElements) {
            if (i >= arrayOfElements.length) {
                return
            }
            cy.get(arrayOfElements[i])
                .then($element => {
                    if ($element.html().includes("source") &&
                        $element.html().includes("source") &&
                        i < arrayOfElements.length
                    ) {
                        return arrayOfElements[i].click()
                    } else {
                        i++
                        return checkElementsAdnClick(arrayOfElements)
                    }
                })
        }

        checkElementsAdnClick(elements)
    }
)
```

Comment: If there are multiple elements matching the condition in above case how to break the loop after 1st match is found

Comment: I edtted part 2 again with the final working version

Comment: Thanks Rosen.The logic you provided is working fine.I have tested all the possible scenarios and it's working fine.

Thank you so much.